# Why am I getting sporadic disconnects when using capybara-webkit gem in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, webkit, capybara, capybara-webkit

I use the `capybara-webkit` gem to scrape data from certain pages in my Rails application.  I've noticed, what seems to be "random" / "sporadic", that the application will crash with the following error:

```
Capybara::Webkit::ConnectionError: /home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/bin/webkit_server failed to start.
    from /home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/lib/capybara/webkit/server.rb:56:in `parse_port'
    from /home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/lib/capybara/webkit/server.rb:42:in `discover_port'
    from /home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/lib/capybara/webkit/server.rb:26:in `start'
    from /home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/lib/capybara/webkit/connection.rb:67:in `start_server'
    from /home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/lib/capybara/webkit/connection.rb:17:in `initialize'
    from /home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/lib/capybara/webkit/driver.rb:16:in `new'
    from /home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/lib/capybara/webkit/driver.rb:16:in `initialize'
    from /home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/lib/capybara/webkit.rb:15:in `new'
    from /home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/lib/capybara/webkit.rb:15:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/session.rb:85:in `driver'
    from /home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/session.rb:233:in `visit'
```

It happens even after it's already connected and accessed a website multiple times before.  Here's a code snippet of what I'm using currently...

```
if site.url.present?

  begin
    # Visit the URL
    session = Capybara::Session.new(:webkit)
    session.visit(site.url)  # here is where the error occurs...
    document = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(session.body)

    # Load configuration options for Development Group
    roster_table_selector = site.development_group.table_selector
    header_row_selector   = site.development_group.table_header_selector
    row_selector   = site.development_group.table_row_selector
    row_offset     = site.development_group.table_row_selector_offset
    header_format_type    = site.config_header_format_type

    # Get the Table and Header Row for processing
    roster_table        = document.css(roster_table_selector)
    header_row          = roster_table.css(header_row_selector)
    header_hash         = retrieve_headers(header_row, header_format_type)

    my_object = process_rows(roster_table, header_hash, site, row_selector, row_offset)

  rescue ::Capybara::Webkit::ConnectionError => e
    raise e

  rescue OpenURI::HTTPError => e
    if e.message == '404 Not Found'
      raise "404 Page not found..."
    else
      raise e
    end
  end
end
```

I've even thought perhaps I don't find out why it's happening necessarily - but just recover when it does.  So I was going to do a "retry" in the rescue block for the error but it appears the server is just down - so I get the same result when retrying.  Perhaps someone knows of a way I can check if the server is down and restart it then perform a retry?  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

So after further investigating it appears that I was generating a new `Capybara::Session` for each iteration of my loop.  I moved it outside of the loop and also added `Capybara.reset_sessions!` at the end of my loop.  Not sure if that helps with anything -- but the issue seems to have been resolved.  I'll monitor it for the next hour or so. Below is an example of my ActiveJob code now...

```
class ScrapeJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default
  include Capybara::DSL

  def perform(*args)

    session = Capybara::Session.new(:webkit)

    Site.where(config_enabled: 1).order(:code).each do |site|
      process_roster(site, session)
      Capybara.reset_sessions!
    end

  end

  def process_roster(site, session)

    if site.roster_url.present?

      begin
        # Visit the Roster URL 
        session.visit(site.roster_url)
        document = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(session.body)

        # processing code...

        # pass the session that was created as the final parameter..
        my_object = process_rows( ..., session)

      rescue ::Capybara::Webkit::ConnectionError => e
        raise e

      rescue OpenURI::HTTPError => e
        if e.message == '404 Not Found'
          raise "404 Page not found..."
        else
          raise e
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You probably don't want to be calling Capybara.reset_sessions! since if you ever move to processing multiple sessions in parallel that could be really bad --  just call   `session.reset!` to only reset the session you're actually using